# Interesting cube subdivisions: what is going on here, and what are these polytopes?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, solid-geometry, polytopes

I was messing around recently with a unit cube.

If you draw vertices on the midpoint of each edge of the cube, then connect those points by new edges, you will form the wireframe of what I figured out is a cuboctohedron. If you repeat this process on the cuboctohedron (drawing vertices on the midpoints of the edges of the cuboctohedron and connecting them with new edges, you form the wireframe of what I discovered was the rhombicuboctohedron. Repeating this, you end up on the 3rd iteration with another polytope which eludes my identification.

I started drawing net maps of these things and I still don't know what the 3rd+ iteration polytopes actually are. The vertices, edges, and faces are as follows for each iteration (if this helps).

iteration: 1  ,       2   ,     3    ,      4    ,     5 ...

vertices: 8, 12, 24, 48, 96, 192 ...

faces: 6, 14, 26, 50, 98, 196 ...

edges: 12, 24, 48, 96, 192, 386 ...

I can't wrap my mind around why this creates these polytopes. Any ideas?
Also, what are the polytopes in the 3+ iterations?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: For a picture of your polytope after $3^{rd}$ and $4^{th}$ iteration, see my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1622118/59379) to a related question (upper right $= 3^{rd}$, lower left $= 4^{th}$ in the picture there). Please note that last two figure in that picture do not equal to your $5^{th}$ and $6^{th}$ iteration.

Comment: The $3^{rd}$ one is an [expanded cuboctahedron/rectified rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_cuboctahedron) . The $4^{th}$ one should probably be called expanded rhombicuboctahedron but I can't find a reference for that.

Comment: On George Hart's ["Conway Notation for Polyhedra"](http://www.georgehart.com/virtual-polyhedra/conway_notation.html) page, your construction corresponds to the "ambo" operation. Thus, in Conway notation, your polyhedra are "C" (cube), "aC", "aaC", "aaaC", etc.